# Подключение RabbitMQ к Glassfish(Payara) в качестве jms провайдера

Tags: java, glassfish, rabbitmq, jms, payara

Есть веб-приложение, которое должно использовать в качестве jms-провайдера использовать RabbitMQ.

В настройках server-config создал своего хоста:
[image: конфигурация хоста]

Далее сделал его используемым по умолчанию и попытался пропинговать к rabbitmq:
[image: Ошибка при пинговании]

[image: Продолжение настроек jms]

В логах:

> [2019-01-16T22:00:39.082+0300] [Payara 5.183] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service] [tid: _ThreadID=221 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1547665239082] [levelValue: 900] [[
>     RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ test_jms_adapter-Connection-Pool ], MQJMSRA_MC4001: constructor:Aborting:JMSException on createConnection=[C4003]: Error occurred on connection creation [localhost:7676]. - cause: java.net.ConnectException: В соединении отказано (Connection refused), error code: C4003]]
>
> [2019-01-16T22:00:39.460+0300] [Payara 5.183] [SEVERE] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=223 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1547665239460] [levelValue: 1000] [[
>     RestResponse.getResponse() gives FAILURE.  endpoint = 'http://localhost:4848/management/domain/servers/server/server/jms-ping?target=server'; attrs = '{}']]

Находил сайт, где объяснялось, как подключить ActiveMQ, для этого они деплоили библиотеку-коннектор. Попробовал также:
[image: Попытка загрузить коннектор]

На самом RabbitMQ даже намёка на попытку подключения нет:
[image: Статистика с RabbitMQ]

[image: Подключения на RabbitMQ сервере]

Answer (score 0):

Как верно подметил автор, для поключения в Payara какого-нибудь брокера на AMQP протоколе (например ActiveMQ или RabbitMQ) под JMS API необходимо задеплоить коннектор. И если в случае ActiveMQ, такой коннектор есть и показан в озвученном примере (ActiveMQ RAR - адаптер, используемый для интеграции ActiveMQ c Java EE контейнерами, например GlassFish), то для RabbitMQ, мне не известен аналогичный адаптер.

Что же касательно rabbitmq jms client, который Вы пытаетесь задеплоить, то он является всего лишь JMS клиентом. Для того чтобы GlassFish контейнер к нему подключился, необходимо выполнить условия описанные в документации [Enabling the JMS client in a Java container](https://www.rabbitmq.com/jms-client.html#java-container). Как Вы можете там прочесть, итоговый рецепт зависит от контейнера. Буду рад, если у вас получится настроить Rabbimq для GlassFish и Вы этим поделитесь.

Comment: Добавлю ещё, что в Payara по умолчанию используется OpenAMQ jms client. Имеет смысл поискать способ интеграции OpenAMQ клиента c RabbitMQ.